# Change the color of the message UIAlertController in Swift

Tags: swift, uicolor, uialertcontroller

I want to change the color of message in UIAlertController in swift. The default is black I want to change it red.

My UIAlertController looks like follows:

```
alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "Invalid Name", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
alert.view.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler:{ (UIAlertAction)in
}))
self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: {
    println("completion block")
})
```

I want to change the color of **Invalid Name** in the above alert box.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use `attributedStrings` to create the color, font, size, and style that you want, and then set the string as the title.

EDIT: Updated with example

```
let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "Invalid Name", attributes: [
  NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle,
  NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.systemFontOfSize(15),
  NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.redColor()
])
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "", preferredStyle: .Alert)

alert.setValue(attributedString, forKey: "attributedMessage")

let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel",
    style: .Default) { (action: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
}

presentViewController(alert,
    animated: true,
    completion: nil)
```

Comment: pbush25, Thanks for you reply. But It is giving me errors on attributes and paragraphStyle

Comment: @Amit Raj sorry I missed a colon right after attributes. Also you can remove the paragraph style since you didn't sound like you needed it based on your question.

Comment: Did you have any issues with App Store submission by using this private API?

Comment: I personally haven't used this in a submitted app, but I don't think you should have problems.

Comment: Is it possible to assign different text colours to the different actions of the alert? I was using alertcontroller.view.tintColor = myColor but it's always the same color for all buttons.

Comment: @nontomatic as far as I know the only way you can change the color of the buttons without creating your own subclass is by choosing different button types (i.e .Cancel .Default .Destructive etc.)

Comment: It should be noted that this code can crash on any future iOS update since it is setting a private, undocumented property of `UIAlertController`. This is unwise. It is better to write or find a custom alert class that properly supports attributed text.

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 5**

```
    let messageString  = "The message to display"
    var myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString()
    myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: messageString as String, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font:UIFont(name: "Poppins-medium", size: 14.0)!])
    myMutableString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.blue, range: NSRange(location:0,length:messageString.count))
    alert.setValue(myMutableString, forKey: "attributedMessage")
```

Comment: Your code doesn't even compile. `alert` is not declared, you are force-uncasting a proprietary font, you are using `UIColor.primaryColor` which probably comes from your own codebase.

Comment: @ Pierre Espenan you should write the alert codes yourself. it's just for the custom font.

Comment: Did you receive any App Store Submission problems??